# Multiple One-to-many relationship on java Appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, persistence, jdo

In googleappengine using JDO, is it possible to have multiple relationships between a model and another models?:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
    public class User {

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Key id;

@Persistent
private String nickname;

@Persistent(mappedBy = "user")
private List<Project> projects;

@Persistent(mappedBy = "user")
private List<File> files;

@Persistent(mappedBy = "user")
private Config config;
....
```

I'm having problems and I'm not sure if it is because appengine doesn't support this kind of relationships.

Comment: "I'm having problems" - what problems? Be specific.

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to add new "projects" to the user by calling: `user.getProjects().add(project);` 
but the entity 'Project' never appear on the Datastore Viewer. I don't get any error message.

Comment: Yes, but *when* are you adding projects ? Quote your persistence code, transaction boundaries, etc. The log tells you plenty

Comment: I think I've fixed the problem. The id on the model 'Project' was defined as Long. When I changed the type to Key the data showed up on the datastore viewer. Also definig the fields as     @Element(dependent = "true") when deleting the User all other fields where deleted. Thanks for your time.